# Does this crater have any relevance?

Tags: diablo-iii

On the Wortham Bluffs (near the spider cave), there's a crater akin to the one that was caused by the Fallen Star:

[image]

However, I have not seen it mentioned anywhere, and this is the only other crater I've seen so far.

What is it? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's where the hilt of Tyrael's sword landed in Wortham - from its landing point there, it seems to have tumbled into the water and then been dredged up by one of the Wortham fishermen.

One of the lore items - Priest's Contemplations, Part 1 - explains further.

> One of the men retrieved a strange artifact in his nets. It looked like the hilt of an ancient blade, but I know it must be more. The fisherman argued with me, but I convinced him to leave it in the safety of the chapel. A holy place for a holy relic.
>
> Verrall, Priest of Wortham

There are similar craters where you obtain the two shards of the sword at the Khazra Den and the Drowned Temple - and where you find the Fallen Star himself, of course - bringing it all together neatly.

Comment: Now, if angels would stop tumbling to the Earth, maybe we could keep our ground intact.

Comment: Angelic terraforming by way of exile? Sounds like an alternate plan for Imperius to destroy humanity. That guy just can't leave well enough alone, can he?